# JpGraph Works on Localhost but Doesn't Work When Website Uploaded

Tags: php, web, localhost, jpgraph

I'm using JpGraph for one of my project. The JpGraph works perfectly on localhost. However, when I uploaded the website to a website hosting, the same graph doesn't appear. It appears as a broken image.

no error message is returned (I have used ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);). I also tried to make a simple page where I echo the  < img src="example2.php" >

but it is the same. It works on localhost but doesn't on the web.

Any idea?

Comment: Check if is activated gd library on your hosting and acces to cache  http://jpgraph.net/doc/faq.php#F1-3